# Object Tag not functionating properly with image and pdf files in angular

Tags: html, angular, object

I am working on a project where I need to show images in an accordion manner but this image can be of any type. Either jpeg, png, pdf or even excel. So to showcase as much as possible we have used `<object>` in which we are passing link to data. But somehow I am not getting the image or pdf iver hear in accordion.

HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr class="table_rows" *ngFor="let row of operationsTableData;let i = index" (click)="onOperationRowClicked(row,i)" [ngClass]="{'active' : activeRow !== null && (i === activeRow)}">
                <td class="oper_row">{{row.OPRSEQUENCENO}}</td>
                <td class="oper_row">{{row.CKEY}}</td>
                <td class="oper_row">{{langFlag == 'en' ? row.Status.en : row.Status.fr}}</td>
    </tr>

//Some more code here

</table>
<div class="img_container">
        <div id="myCarousel" *ngIf="imageList.length" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" *ngFor="let element of imageList;let i=index" [ngClass]="{'active': i==0}">
              <object [data]="element.sanitizedUrl" [ngClass]="{pdf_resize: element.type=='pdf'}" >
                <div class="doc_unsupported">Document type not supported.&#13;Please click the above icon to download.</div>
              </object>
              <div class="overlay_absolute_div" (click)="openItem(element.FILE_PATH)"><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control active" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="fas fa-chevron-left" style="color: white;"></span>
            
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control active" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="fas fa-chevron-right"style="color: white;"></span>
          
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

TS file code

```
this.operationsTableData.forEach(element => {
        if(element["AttachmentsDetail"]) {
          element["AttachmentsDetail"].forEach(file => {
            file['FILE_PATH'] = `http://${window.location.hostname}:${window.location.port}/chronos/workbookModal/operationFile${file['FILE_PATH']}` 
            file['sanitizedUrl'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(file['FILE_PATH'])
          });
        }
        element['Images']= element["AttachmentsDetail"] && (element["AttachmentsDetail"]).length ? (element["AttachmentsDetail"]).filter(value => value.forCarousel == 1) : [];
      });
```

Here as you can see we are using sanitized URL because we are running it onver http and the server from where the images are coming is different. The point over here is when we are directly binding the same URL or work it with iframe it is working fine. But when we are trying to do the same with `<object>` tag, that time it is now giving anything except blank space. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KJ Its in angular and when we need to use it with variables of angular we need to use [data].

Comment: I got the solution. It happens that for object you need to reload it whenever you are binding any dynamic data. And for that I was not getting the answer. Now I got it via appending the object dynamically. @KJ Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Turn out to be when you are using an `<object>` tag and you are using dynamic values under `[data]` than that time you need to reload the component. If you are getting data in `ngoninit` and binding it directly then it will work properly but when you are getting data on change event that time it is not rendering the `[data]` value. So we simply passed `<object>` tag from ts file and it started working correctly.

```
onOperationRowClicked(row,index) {
    this.selectedOperation = row
    this.imageList = this.selectedOperation.Images
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.imageList.forEach((element, index)=>{
        var object = document.getElementById(`obj-${index}`);
        var object2 = document.getElementById(`iconno-${index}`);
        object.innerHTML = `<object data="${element.FILE_PATH}" 
       [ngClass]="{pdf_resize: element.type=='pdf'}" >
        <div class="doc_unsupported">Please select the Operation Row to see the image / pdf file</div>
      </object>`
        object.appendChild(object2)
       })
    }, 0);
  }
```

This might not be the correct way to do it but atleast I got the solution which I wanted.